# Storing a string in struct via an argument to a function

Tags: c, linked-list, c-strings

I'm struggling to figure out how to pass a string into a function and then how to store it in struct via pointer. I want to create a linked list where each node contains a node name(string) and data(integer) representing the weight required to reach that node.

The structure representing the node is as follows:

```
struct ListNode
{
    // The energy required to reach in this node
    int data;
    // The name of the node
    char location[20];

    // And the nodes along side this one
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
};
```

The following function generates a node and sets its next and previous pointers:

```
// Allocate a new listNode with the provided value
struct ListNode* listNodeConstructor(int value, char *city)
{
    struct ListNode* newNode;

    // Reserve memory for a node
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));

    // Set its values
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->name = strdup(city); /* This is how I've tried to implement it but it causes an error */
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;

    // And return it
    return newNode;
}
```

If anyone can show me how to correctly store the string in the node struct, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Can you please clarify/correct the apparent conflict between the `location` member of your structure (in the definition) and the `name` member in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strdup()` copies a string to a newly malloced place in the heap and returns a pointer to the new string.

Note that you also need to `free` it.

The problem is, that the string you want to set is part of the structure and not just a pointer you can set.

You have two options:

- Use `strcpy(newNode->name,city);` instead of `newNode->name = strdup(city);`. This copies the city string to `newNode` but you need to assure that `city` has a `\0` until `newNode->name` overflows.
- change `name` to be just a pointer and free it when you free the node. You can use `strdup` in that case. (Change `char location[20];` to `char *location;`

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign arrays. You can only assign scalar variables or structs or unions

```
struct ListNode
{
    // The energy required to reach in this node
    int data;
    // The name of the node
    char *name;
    char name1[32];
    struct ListNode* next;
    struct ListNode* prev;
};

int foo(struct ListNode *node, const char *str)
{
    node -> name = str; // but remember that it only assigns the 
                        //reference and does not copy the string
    /* OR */
    node -> name = strdup(str); // but remember to free it
    strcpy(node -> name1, str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are attempting to use [strdup (3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) which creates a copy of the string in a newly heap allocated space. You are therefore attempting to assign a pointer (which is the return of your `strdup` to a char array. As you already have allocated your string space in your structure, you should therefore use [strcpy (3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) instead in the following way: `strcpy(newNode->name, city)`.

Also please note it is always a good practice to pass pointer parameters as `const` when you do not intend to modify them. This convention aims to improve readability and is very helpful when you want to debug your programs when they grow bigger.